# Multiple Backgroundworkers + C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Quick question - is it possible to have two background workers running at once?  I seem to remember trying this once and getting an error, and also seem to remember reading that you can only have one...  I can't find another thread that talks about having more than one explicitly though..

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can have as many background workers as you like and running simultaneously. Example:

```
var worker1 = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
var worker2 = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
DoWorkEventHandler doWork = (sender, e) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var progress = (int)((i + 1) * 100.0 / 10);
        var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        worker.ReportProgress(progress);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
};
worker1.DoWork += doWork;
worker2.DoWork += doWork;
worker1.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
};
worker2.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    label2.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
};

worker1.RunWorkerAsync();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
worker2.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Why not create separate doWork delegates for worker1 and worker2?

Comment: For the sake of example it wasn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the example as a picture